# R shiny doesn't reset fileInput and and keeps it in memory

Tags: r, file-io, reset, shiny

I'm working with a R Shiny app that takes two shapefiles in input and then intersects them together and calculates the area. 
I want to reset and remove the second shapefile in input when the first shapefile is uploaded so at the new analysis I want to set the second shapefile (`file2`) as NULL. 
I tried using `shinyjs::reset("file2")` but the second shapefile (`input$file2`) is still in memory and when I upload a new shapefile (`file1`, `input$file1`) and then click on analysis button (whithout upload another `file2`) the app starts analysis such as `file2` was not resetted.

This is the code that I'm using:

## library and function

```
      library(shiny)
      library(shinyjs)
      library(leaflet)
      library(mapview)
      library(rgdal)
      library(rgeos)
      library(maptools)
      library(DT)


        fIntersect<-function(file1,file2){
        CRSfrom <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m+no_defs")
        CRSto   <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
        shpInt <- disaggregate(intersect(file1, file2))
        shpInt@data$area<- round(gArea(shpInt, byid = TRUE) / 10000,digits= 2)
        IntData<-data.table(shpInt@data)
        return(list("IntData"=IntData))           
        }
```

## ui.R

```
    ui <- fluidPage( 
    useShinyjs(),
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose File',multiple = TRUE),
    fileInput('file2', 'Choose File',multiple = TRUE),
    actionButton("Analize", "Analize"),

    box(leafletOutput("Map",width ="100%")),  

    box(dataTableOutput("IntData"))),
```

## server.R

```
    server <- function(input, output) {
    #CRS setting            
    CRSfrom <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
    CRSto   <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

    #Render Input file and upload           
    output$Map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%setView(16,40,zoom=6)%>%
            addTiles() })


    output$file1 <- renderText({
        file1 <- input$file1
        if (is.null(input$file1))
            return(NULL)
    })

    output$file2 <- renderText({
        file2 <- input$file2
        if (is.null(file2))
            return(NULL)
    })


    uploadfile1 <- reactive({
        if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
            shpDF <- input$file1
            prevWD <- getwd()
            uploadDirectory <- dirname(shpDF$datapath[1])
            setwd(uploadDirectory)
            for (i in 1:nrow(shpDF)) {
                file.rename(shpDF$datapath[i], shpDF$name[i])
            }
            shpName <- shpDF$name[grep(x = shpDF$name, pattern = "*.shp")]
            shpPath <- paste(uploadDirectory, shpName, sep = "/")
            setwd(prevWD)
            file <- readShapePoly(shpPath,
                                  proj4string =CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
            return(file)


        } else {
            return(NULL)
        }
    })

    uploadfile2 <- reactive({
        if (!is.null(input$file2)) {
            shpDF <- input$file2
            prevWD <- getwd()
            uploadDirectory <- dirname(shpDF$datapath[1])
            setwd(uploadDirectory)
            for (i in 1:nrow(shpDF)) {
                file.rename(shpDF$datapath[i], shpDF$name[i])
            }
            shpName <- shpDF$name[grep(x = shpDF$name, pattern = "*.shp")]
            shpPath <- paste(uploadDirectory, shpName, sep = "/")
            setwd(prevWD)
            file <- readShapePoly(shpPath,
                                  proj4string =CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
            return(file)
        } 
        else {
            return(NULL)
        }
    })

    output$IntData  <- renderDataTable(datatable(data.table("id" = "0")))

    observeEvent(input$file1, {
        # Show upload polygon on Map
        shinyjs::reset('file2')
        leafletProxy("Map")%>%clearGroup(c("file1")) ####
        shpUpload <- spTransform(uploadfile1(), CRSto)
        leafletProxy("Map") %>%
            addPolygons(data = shpUpload,
                        color = "#33a02c",
                        group = "file1",
                        fill = FALSE,
                        weight = 2.5)
    })

    observeEvent(input$file2, {
        # Show upload polygon on Map
        leafletProxy("Map")%>%clearGroup(c("file2")) ####
        shpUpload <- spTransform(uploadfile2(), CRSto)
        leafletProxy("Map") %>% 
            addPolygons(data = shpUpload,
                        color = "#33a02c",
                        group = "file2",
                        fill = FALSE,
                        weight = 2.5)
    })


    #Start analysis            
    observeEvent(input$Analize,{

        if(input$Analize>0){ withProgress(message = "Sto eseguendo l'analisi...",
                             value =0, {
                             Intersection<-fIntersect(uploadfile1(),uploadfile2())
                             observe({
                             output$IntData<-renderDataTable({
                             datatable(Intersection$IntData)
                             })
                       })

                 }
        )
        }else{}

    }

    )
    #End Analysis            
}
```

shinyApp(ui, server)

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: i guess the issue lies in _function call_ ie. when `input$file1, input$file2` are uploaded, operations under **observeEvent** are executed once. But when you upload files 2nd time, **Note:** `input$file1, input$file2` still are initialized with old values, so no `observeEvent`s are triggered.

You need create `observeEvent` operations as `reactive` functions and call them in when files are read in server

Answer (score 2):

This code shows how to create your own reativeValues to gain the control you want.  First create your own writable reactive values, then use those instead of input.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage( 
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose File',multiple = TRUE),
  fileInput('file2', 'Choose File',multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton("Analize", "Analize"),
  # Show the state of the input files
  verbatimTextOutput('file1'),
  verbatimTextOutput('file2'),
  # This will change only when the action button is used
  verbatimTextOutput('look_at_input')
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Create your own reactive values that you can modify because input is read only 
  rv <- reactiveValues() 

  # Do something when input$file1 changes 
  # * set rv$file1, remove rv$file2
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    rv$file1=input$file1
    rv$file2=NULL
  })

  # Do something when input$file2 changes
  # * Set rv$file2
  observeEvent(input$file2, {
    rv$file2=input$file2
  })

  # Show the value of rv$file1 
  output$file1 <- renderPrint ({ str(rv$file1) })

  # Show the value of rv$file2 
  output$file2 <- renderPrint({ str(rv$file2) })


  #Start analysis            
  # Do something when the Analize button is selected
  look_at_input<-eventReactive(input$Analize,{
    list(rv$file1,rv$file2)
  })
  output$look_at_input <-renderPrint({ str( look_at_input()    )})

  #End Analysis            
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! reactiveValues is the answer for my problem!